# Setting visible to shape within Tween

Tags: createjs

I want set visibility to shape on the following manner

```
var shape = new cjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill("#0000FF").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
movieClip.addTween(
    createjs.Tween.get(shape)
        .to({visible: true}, 50)
        .to({visible: false}, 50)
   );
```

But is doesn't work? How I can do it?

Comment: has the shape been added as a child of the MovieClip?

Comment: Hm, Why? 
 I can change setting visible to x like
        .to({x: 100}, 50)
        .to({x: 200}, 50)
and it will works fine, without any adding shape to MovieClip children.
And How I can add shape to MovieClip children? Sorry for silk question, but createjs documentation has a lot of lacks

Answer (score 1):

Setting visible *does* work, but it probably doesn't work how you think. What is happening in your code is this:

1. Add "shape" to the movieClip at frame 0
2. Tween to `{visible:true}` in 50 frames. Non-numeric properties can not tween, so they are just set immediately at the end of the tween. This means the shape goes from visible at the start, to still visible at frame 50.
3. Tween to `{visible:false}` in 50 more frames. The shape will be visible until the very end of the second tween.
4. Loop. MovieClips will loop their timelines unless told otherwise. CreateJS tweens store initial properties when created, and will reset to those values when going to frame 0. This makes tweens deterministic, so you can set the position to anywhere in the timline, and it will look how you expect.

This means it is visible for the whole timeline, with *maybe* 1 frame at the end where it is invisible, but then it resets and plays again.

Here is a quick sample where it tweens to visible, then invisible, then visible again: http://jsfiddle.net/99bxn6j5/1/

```
mc.timeline.addTween(
    createjs.Tween.get(shape)
        .to({x: 100, visible:false}, 40)
        .to({x: 200, visible:true}, 40)
        .to({x: 300, visible:false}, 40)
   );
```

I am not sure what your desired result is, but you will probably need to change the approach to get it working.